# Exception Handling : AOP vs Classic Handling?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, aop, spring.net

I'm upgrading a **Plugin Loading Engine** (`.NET`) which does the following :

1. Loads Plugins
2. Connects them to the appropriate Data Source
3. Launchs the Plugins
4. Displays the results

All the plugins implement the same Interface : `IPlugin`and each one is launched in a separate `BackGroundWorker`. All the `BackgroundWorkers` are managed by a module called `Host`.

My problem is the `Errors/Exceptions Handling`.  The engine is already deployed and I want to find an elegant way to handle the `Errors/Exceptions` that could be thrown when the plugins run. Some `Exceptions` are caught in the plugins but not all of them.

I was thinking about a separate layer that could catch the errors and treat them for all the plugins.

I imagined a kind of `Context` attached to each `Plugin` which contain its progress level (`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`), its status, the thrown exceptions(using the `RunWorkerCompletedEvent`) but the errors are thrown only after the `BackgroundWorker` stops. I would like to interrupt it when an exception is thrown.

I was also thinking that Aspect Oriented Programming could be a great way. I took a look on the net and found some framework like **Spring.NET**. But not sure if it could be appropriate in my case.

**[UPDATE]**
Here are more design details as requested :

- IPlugin Interface : Called `AbstractEnvChecker` :

[image: AbstractEnvChecker]

The application is a **Rich Client App**. After compiling the plugins, the generated `DLL` are loaded and a List is displayed to the users in a simple Windows Form. The user selects then the plugins to launch and the `Plugin.DoWork()` method is called.

And here is how the **Host** launches the selected Plugins :

```
void LaunchPlugin(AbstractEnvChecker p_Plugin)
{
    if (p_Plugin != null)
    {
        BackgroundWorker l_BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        l_BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        l_BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        l_BackgroundWorker.DoWork +=
            new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        l_BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged +=
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        l_BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

        m_PluginByThreadMap.Add(l_BackgroundWorker, p_Plugin);
        l_BackgroundWorker.DoWork += p_Plugin.DoWork;
        l_BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(l_BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        l_BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(p_Plugin);
    }
}
```

Is `AOP` an appropriate solution to add the Error Handling Layer ?

Comment: Gotta run, but I figured I'd throw out PostSharp as an option to consider for AOP as well.  Can't comment on the implications/questions you have there, but I'm definitely interested in the discussion and answers. :)

Comment: Can you post an example of your backgroundWorker to your Plugin context?

Comment: And what does you `IPlugin` interface look like? And what kind of application is this: rich client, console app / scheduled task ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just wrap the `IPlugin.DoWork()` method in a `try/catch` clause. something like this:

`l_BackgroundWorker.DoWork += (o, e) => ExecutePlugin(o, e, p_plugin);`

```
private void ExecutePlugin(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, IPlugin plugin)
{   
   try 
   { 
      plugin.DoWork(o, e);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      //do something with the error. disable the plugin maybe?
   }
}
```

If this work then using Spring just for the Error handling is a bit overkill in my opinion.

Something additional you could do is throwing a custom exception (e.g. a `PluginException`) and handle those globally in your Application, this can be achieved by attaching to:
`Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` events

Comment: I agree, but the question was how aop *could* be used here, and what it would look like.

Comment: @Marijn One of his points is `Is AOP a good solution to add the Error Handling Layer ? Or should i keep the solution i mentioned and develop it (ideas are welcome) ?` so in my opinion using AOP and Spring.net *just* because of the error handling is not a good solution and is overkill

Comment: I fully agree; missed the overkill part of your answer when I first read it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring.net uses dynamic weaving, which basically means that at runtime Spring.net aop can wrap exception handlers around method calls. But Spring.net aop needs a seam to position it's interceptor in.

If your plugins should be loaded into a UI, then the user (probably) can invoke methods that don't go through the host or `IPlugin` interface at all, making it hard (if not impossible) for spring.net aop to intercept and wrap exception handlers.

If your host is a console application or service that calls `myPlugin.DoWork()`, then it's definitely possible to intercept any exceptions thrown by the plugin using Spring.net aop. If you could provide a bit more detail (see comments to your question) then I can show you how to do this.

Below an example that uses Spring.net AOP to proxy a plugin instance and wrap it with an interceptor, that catches a thrown exception and delegates it back to the host. Note that you can do this without AOP too ... that's up to you.

```
using System;
using AopAlliance.Intercept;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Spring.Aop.Framework;

namespace Aop
{

    [TestFixture]
    public class SimpleProxyFactoryTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Main()
        {
            var host = new Host();

            var mp = new SimplePlugin(); 
            var pf = new ProxyFactory(mp);
            pf.AddAdvice(new DelegateToHostExceptionHandlingAdvice(host));

            var proxy = (IPlugin)pf.GetProxy();

            proxy.DoWork();
        }
    }

    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void DoWork();
    }

    public class Host
    {
        public void HandleExceptionFromPlugin(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling exception: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public class SimplePlugin : IPlugin
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing it and throwing an exception ... ");

            throw new ApplicationException("Oops!");
        }
    }

    public class DelegateToHostExceptionHandlingAdvice : IMethodInterceptor 
    {
        private readonly Host _host;

        public DelegateToHostExceptionHandlingAdvice(Host host)
        {
            _host = host;
        }

        public object Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation)
        {
            try
            {
                return invocation.Proceed();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 _host.HandleExceptionFromPlugin(ex);
                return null; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Discussion

I hope I've shown you how you could leverage an aop framework to do exception handling. As [Sebastian mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250975/322283), using Spring aop *only* for exception wrapping might be considered overkill - and I agree; compare the simplicity of his code example to the complexity of mine. Imagine explaining either one to a new developer on your team.

Spring aop starts to "shine" when you use it in combination with the Spring IOC container.

Comment: Yes, the Host launches the Plugins by calling the `myPlugin.DoWork()` method, I added more details ...

Comment: That's more clear ... I'll show you a possible solution later today.